# Como saber el tipo de campo de la base de datos con EntityFramewors C# [UWP]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, uwp

Es que tengo una tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE Parametros(
    Empid       int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [FK_Parametros_Empid] REFERENCES Empresa(id),
    Codigo      varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    Valor       sql_variant NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Parametros] PRIMARY KEY (Empid,Codigo))
```

Y pues cuando quiero saber que dato tengo almacenado en `Valor` hago esta consulta:

```
SELECT Empid, 
       Codigo,
       Valor, 
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(Valor,'BaseType') AS 'DataTypell'
FROM Parametros
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y pues me lo trae en SQL pero nesecito traer ese dato en C# cuando hago la consulta en Entity Frameworks ¿como lo traigo?

de momento tengo un metodo asi:

```
public async Task<Parametro> GetAsync(int empid)
{
    return await _db.Parametro.FindAsync(empid);
}
```